# Plotting column wise data ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given:

```
x <- data.frame(Day = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                var1 = c(5,4,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4),
                var2 = c(3,6,2,3,4,5,7,8,1,2),
                var3 = c(1,2,3,4,6,2,4,7,8,4),
                var4 = c(1,3,7,5,3,7,2,3,1,2))
```

I'm looking to create a bar graph that displays Day 1 to 10 on the X-axis and the variables mean on the Y.

Here's the solution provided in the comments:

```
x$avg <- rowMeans(x[2:5]) # your question asked for an average

require(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = x, aes(x = Day, y = avg)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + # use identity to map the bar to actual value
  stat_summary(aes(label=round(..y..,2)), # labels the bar with the value
               fun.y=mean, geom="text", size=6,
               vjust = -0.5)
```

Comment: That's a pretty broad/vague question. How exactly have you tried to create your chart, and what about it is not working? There are tons of tutorials (e.g., [here](http://tutorials.iq.harvard.edu/R/Rgraphics/Rgraphics.html)) that can help you get started with ggplot2.

Comment: This is close to what I want, but I'd like to set the y-axis to track the value of the bars as opposed to a count.
  x %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= var1))+
  geom_histogram()+
  facet_grid(~Day)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
x$avg <- rowMeans(x[2:5]) # your question asked for an average

require(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = x, aes(x = Day, y = avg)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + # use identity to map the bar to actual value
  stat_summary(aes(label=round(..y..,2)), # labels the bar with the value
               fun.y=mean, geom="text", size=6,
               vjust = -0.5)
```

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I needed.

Do you have any recommended sources to read up on stat_summary, fun, etc? I have a basic understanding of ggplot now but had no idea those functions existed! 

One more question, is there anyway to ask it to label the X-axis individually? At the moment, that code plots the Day on the X axis but only has ticks at every 2.5-- which doesn't exactly make the most sense when there are 10 bars that correspond to 10 levels. (only 4 tickets at this point).

Comment: One way is add this: `+ scale_x_discrete(limits = 1:10)`. Lots of resources: http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/index.html has links to them along with its own examples and such.

Comment: Thanks! Another way is to just as.factor(Day) and it'll do the job.